# Ionic2, how do I get contentHeight during initialization

Tags: initialization, ionic2

When I switch to a Tab Page for the first time, I'd like to do some initialization using the `contentHeight` of the `ion-content`, but I can't find the correct place to do it. Here's what I did:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class TestPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content : Content;

  constructor(private nav: NavController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad');
    console.log('\tcontentHeight', this.content.contentHeight);
    console.log('\tscrollHeight', this.content.scrollHeight);

    let element = this.content.getScrollElement();
    console.log('\tclientHeight', element.clientHeight);
  }

  doClick() {
    console.log('doClick');
    console.log('\tcontentHeight', this.content.contentHeight);
    console.log('\tscrollHeight', this.content.scrollHeight);

    let element = this.content.getScrollElement();
    console.log('\tclientHeight', element.clientHeight);
  }
}
```

When running and clicking the button, the result is:

```
ionViewDidLoad
    contentHeight – 0
    scrollHeight – 0
    clientHeight – 568
doClick
    contentHeight – 475
    scrollHeight – 569
    clientHeight – 475
```

The values shown after clicking the button are the ones I need, but I need them earlier during initialization. `ionViewDidLoad` seems to be called before everything is fully initialized.

How can I initialize properly?

Comment: Instead of content:Content; do set content(value){ console.log(value.contentHeight)}

Comment: @misha130, I don't understand exactly what you mean. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I am not sure if giving a class inside a viewchild rather than an ID string is correct so I wont write an answer. What I am suggesting is you put a setter function instead of the content property so you can do stuff once you know its 100% set

Comment: Ah. I took that from the documentation, [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/) so that should be alright. I also did a `console.log(content)` on it and it looks ok.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch data in ionViewDidEnter? During this time, the entire DOM content will be loaded in the screen.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having exact same issue in tabs..